# Need help printing portion of page in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying to print only the summary tab found at this link: http://10.168.22.139/parceldetail/8030021023

Can anybody assist in doing this? I would like everything to be printed the same way it looks on the screen.

I found this solution in another thread and couldn't get it to work:

document.getElementById('portal').contentWindow.document.body.getElementById('pa 
   nel-body ng-scope').print();

This is the full function:

```
function printall(){
    alert("Remember to download the parcelmap and zip code from USPS");
    document.getElementById('portal').contentWindow.document.body.getElementById('panel-body ng-scope').print();
```

}

Only the only alert shows in this case and no print dialog shows at all.

Comment: Is print.css an option? Or only Javascript?

Comment: Yes. CSS would be okay too.

Comment: Are any errors displayed in the Console of the browser's Developer Tools?

Comment: Blocked a frame with origin "http://smp-pw43278:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Are there any css solutions or javascript workarounds for this error?